# rails generate rspec:install gives no error, but manpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

**OS**: Linux Debian Wheezy 
**Rails version**: 3.2.0

I want to configure RSpec to work with Rails. 
I'm using this instruction: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails ('Installation' section).

When I try:

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

after successfully performing all the things described in the manual before, 
I get:

```
Usage: rails new APP_PATH [options]
```

etc.

How to resolve this?

IMHO **Relevant part of my Gemfile**:

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.0'

group :development, :test do
        gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
        gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
end
```

(I'm new to Rails and using M. Hartl manual to learn.) 
(What I have tried already:

- changing Rails version (4.0.0, then to 3.2.0);
- changing rspec version (initially 2.8.0, then to ~> 2.0);
- a few times 'bundle update', 'bundle install' and 'bundle update rspec-rails';
- installing 'rspec' and 'rspec-rails' using 'gem install';

Comment: Are you sure you're in rails dir?

Comment: What do you mean by 'rails dir', Michael? I'm in the directory from that I've installed rails: ~/myapps/app

Comment: dir in which rails app is?

Comment: Yes, I'm in this directory.

Comment: I thought, maybe anyone faced this problem? How can I research it? Maybe, any 'versions mess'?

Comment: what happens if you run `rails s`?

Comment: Suddenly I got the same instruction instead of WEBricks start. And got it after reinstalling rails completely. What's wrong?

Comment: does result of `rails -v` match one in your Gemfile?

Comment: Yes, it does. Somehow a little earlier I was able to start Rails Server without any problem. I think I'll just roll a little back and try it all again  to locate the problem and maybe avoid it, but I'm ready to collaborate to find the causes of this case.

Comment: I think the problem has the same root with the problem of 'rails s -> usage'. Thank you, Michael, for pointing me in this direction!

Comment: Also, '~/ror/sap$ which rails
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/bin/rails' <- is this path normal?

Comment: For RVM I think so. I don't use rvm, just plain ruby 2.0 for all projects

Comment: I've noticed that my app folder simply doesn't contain 'script' subdirectory for some reason. When I've copied this directory from another project, this error with showing 'manpage' disappeared.
But: this is not a solution, because more problems appear with this. I'll simply roll back to the previous v. of this app. Thanks Michael!

Comment: My ANSWER: My application missed 'script' subdirectory for some reason. 
Seems  like Rails had 'nothing to play' and was showing the manual. 

So maybe the comparison with standard RoR application directory structure can be helpful in this situation.

Comment: The CAUSE: I've created this app using the following command: 'rails new appname --skip-test-unit', as followed from M. Hartl manual. But thus 'script' folder was not created! And thus I had no way to start the server or any other scripts.

Comment: Wow, that's strange but I'm glad you solved this.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you install `gem install rails` after June 25, 2013 - it will install the rails 4. When you following the course, Hartl asks you to copy his Gemfile located in his [GitHub repo](https://raw.github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/master/Gemfile) which actually refers to Rails '3.2.14'.

To solve this problem, create a gemset using RVM.

```
rvm gemset create sample_app

rvm gemset use sample_app
```

Then create a Gemfile inside an empty folder.

```
mkdir sample
touch Gemfile
```

Copy the content form the Hartl's (Gemfile)[https://raw.github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_2nd_ed/master/Gemfile] to the Gemfile you just now created and run,

```
bundle install
```

Once all gems are installed, simply go outside the folder and delete it.

```
cd .. && rm -rf sample
```

Now create a new Rails project and skip the auto bundle install.

```
rails new sample --skip-unit-test --skip-bundle
```

Once Rails generated the files, go inside the folder and replace the Gemfile contents again with Hart's Gemfile.

Now run `bundle install`

Finally you can create the RVM file that will automatically switch to the project gemset.

```
rvm --create --ruby-version use ruby-2.0.0@sample-app
```

`ruby-2.0.0` refers to my system's active Ruby version. You'll need to replace this accordingly.

This should work fine. Let me know if you have any further help.

Cheers!